# cannot import name "B" from "A"

Tags: python

I am here to ask what seems to be a very dumb question, but just cannot find a fix for it. I'm just a beginner and I've also searched StackOverflow for multiple results but such problems are not related to mine. If I've missed one, I'm sorry about that.

my problem is that I'm trying to re-create one of my first console games into an OOP one, but for some reason, I cannot import modules?

firs, I would like to say that I created this on my laptop with Pop os. and that the mentioned two file are the only file on the directory.

so I created a `battle_main.py` and `battle_mechanics.py`

on the `battle_mechanics.py`, it only has the following lines:

```
class User_Interface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player_health = 30
        self.squid_health = 30
```

and on the `battle_main.py`:

```
from battle_mechanics import User_Interface

ui = User_Interface()
```

it's literally just that, yet I cannot import it. it's resulting in `ImportError: cannot import name 'User_Interface' from 'battle_mechanics'` I know that it's a very simple problem, but I really can't find any fix to it? in fact, I think there's not even a problem in the way I'm importing it. it just wont work. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually saved the `battle_mechanics.py` file recently?  `import` is only going to look at the file on disk, not the contents of your editor.

Comment: Is the indentation that you've presented here reflective of the indentation you used in your program?

Comment: Where are the two files? And from which directory are you executing them? This should work if you are in the directory where the two files are. E.g. if you are in `project`, and the files in `project/src`, and you try `python src/battle_main.py`, you would likely get that error, as Python would be looking for `project/battle_mechanics.py`, not `project/src/battle_mechanics.py`.

Comment: This code should not produce that error.  You must have made some other mistake.

Comment: @Acccumulation hello, no, the indentation that are presented does not in fact reflect the actual code. just a problem on my part. fixed It!

Comment: @jasonharper a blunder on my part, it seems that I actually didn't save the file before trying to run It! thank you for reminding me of that! I know it there's a very dumb reason it's not working.

Comment: @Amadan the file is in the correct directory, I've doubled check it and also tried it on my windows system. still, any problem that I've searched on about a similar problem such as mine also refers to a problem with the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure as to why the method your trying isn't working. To the best of my knowledge what your doing already is correct. However one alternative workaround is to put `battle_mechanics.py` inside a folder `package`. Include `__init__.py` inside that folder with the following code:

```
from .battle_mechanics import *
```

Then when you use `battle_main.py` you can use the following import statement.

```
from package import User_Interface
```

This should sort out your issue.